# Why does my screensaver *not* activate the logon screen on resume?

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

Some background:

- I'm using **Windows 7**.
- I have the '**Photos**' sreensaver configured.
- I have it set to start after **10 minutes** of inactivity.
- I have it set to '**On resume, display logon screen.**'

The screensaver does start after the prescribed period. However mouse movement leads back to an active PC, and not to the Logon screen as required.

I have tried reducing the time limit to test this, but it appears that my pc no longer locks after the screen saver exits.

FWIW I have tried using Win+L to lock the machine and this does work, but what I really want is for the screen saver to do this automatically.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you also check the advanced settings in the power profile being used?  I am not sure if it could effect it, but the items are there to require password on waking from "sleep" specific.

Comment: There is also a Group Policy item that can be set to effect this, and also some item called "ScreenSaverGracePeriod" that may be in the registry (but it was not in mine default) that gives some time prior to it requiring the locking.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same case in my laptop running with Windows 7. If we move the mouse immediately after the screensaver started, it will goes to active screen. If we disturb the screensaver after few second it started, it will goes to logon screen and ask for password.

Comment: This is because there's a setting that will lock your computer if the screensaver has been on for a certain amount of time. (Which is usually 5 seconds.)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the registry key `DisableLockWorkstation` to 0. It is located here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it works :

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ScreenSaverIsSecure"="1"

You just have to create a Key and assign the value to 1.